# Tagging or some kind of organization of goo.gl links

Tags: goo.gl

I want to organize my links in [goo.gl](http://goo.gl/) with tags or some kind of directory structure.

Currently I can hide links, which I guess, also counts as organizing them.

Is there a way to tag links in goo.gl? Or is there a way to organize them through the directories like in bit.ly?

I use Firefox heavily and would prefer a Firefox plugin if that's the way to go.

Comment: I believe there is no such functionality (like bit.ly bundles). It's not documented in http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=190768 for sure

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tag or organize links by default. My suggestion is to use Delicious to store the shortened links. Delicious is an example, there are other sites such as pinboard, historious, scuttle where you can categorize links.

Comment: Delicious does not shorten links. Plus uncertain future of Delicious makes it a bit of a gamble in the long run...

Comment: @DmitryS - My suggestion is to use Delicious to store the shortened links. Delicious is an example, there are other sites such as pinboard, historious, scuttle where you can categorize links. These will store the shortened URLs. Plus, with Delicious being taken over by AVOS - I don't think it's that much of a gamble.

Comment: Now I see your point. But can you automatically feed goo.gl links to one of those services?

Comment: @DmitryS Not yet, but I see that goo.gl API provides a list of short URLS (ref: http://code.google.com/apis/urlshortener/v1/reference.html#method_urlshortener_url_list ). Hopefully someone can hack an app which would autopost to delicious / other apps whenever a URL is shortened

Comment: @Sathya if there's demand it'll show up. Thanks!

Comment: @DmitryS - Yeah, I hope so. I use [packratius](http://packrati.us) to auto post the links on my twitter stream to delicious, maybe someone will come up with a service similar to this